# How to center rotated text on page in PostScript

Tags: text, rotation, center, ghostscript, postscript

I put text *Sample* on every PDF page using the following PostScript code:

```
<<
   /EndPage {
   exch pop 2 lt { 
     gsave
     /Arial-Bold 120 selectfont
     .5 setgray 100 100 moveto 45 rotate (Sample) show
     grestore
     true}
     {false}
     ifelse
   } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

This puts text on [100; 100] position. But I need to center this text (accounting text is rotated).

How do I align this *45° rotated* text in the center of a page?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `false charpath flattenpath pathbbox` to get the bounding box of the text.
If the currentpoint is `0 0` when you do this, then the lower-left coordinates will be *pretty close to* `0 0`, so the upper-right coordinates describe the width and height of the text. So you just move to the desired center-point and back-up by making a relative move to (-width/2, -height/2).

Since the center of rotation is also the center-point, you need to translate there before rotating.

```
%!
/w 612 def
/h 792 def
/Helvetica-Bold 120 selectfont

w .5 mul h .5 mul translate
0 0 moveto
(Sample) false charpath flattenpath pathbbox % llX llY urX urY
4 2 roll pop pop % urX urY

0 0 moveto
45 rotate
-.5 mul exch -.5 mul exch % -wid/2 -ht/2
rmoveto
(Sample) show
```

For more accuracy, replace `4 2 roll pop pop` with

```
exch % llX llY urY urX
4 1 roll % urX llX llY urY
exch sub % urX llX urY-llY
3 1 roll % urY-llY urX llX
sub exch % urX-llX urY-llY
```

And then the point can be anywhere (but there *does* need to be a currentpoint since `charpath` builds a path just like `show` does, even though `pathbbox` destroys it immediately; so you need some kind of `moveto`).

Comment: Just to be clear, "If the currentpoint is 0 0" the llx and lly are not zero.  The way you do it above is accurate for urx and ury but not llx and lly.  The difference is probably so small that it doesn't make a difference.